# "Unable to write to the configuration file." Error with Magento Connect Manager 1.9.3.2

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

After migrating my Apache server from Ubuntu 14.04 to CentOS 7, I started experiencing these permission errors.

On the Magento Connect Manager login page, I'm hit with an error message and unable to login:

> Unable to write to the configuration file.

The error remained even after I set the permission for every file and folder to 0777.

I then deleted the .cfg files in the "downloader" folder. Now the error message has become:

> Settings has not been loaded. Used default settings Config file does not exists please save Settings Unable to write to the configuration file.

After login/logout, restarting the Apache server and even the entire host, the error remained. The error logs did not record anything at all.

Comment: New Magento installation is having hard time deleting temporary files too, even though the owner and group are all set to what the web server is running as.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved!

SELinux was preventing Apache from writing to the directory.
I used the following command to enable it:

```
chcon -t httpd_sys_rw_content_t /var/www/html -R
```

Answer (score 1):

On [Debian 8.6](https://www.debian.org/News/2016/20160917) with [Magento-1.9.3.6](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/ce19-ee114/ce1.9_release-notes.html#ce19-1936) the [`chown`](http://nersp.nerdc.ufl.edu/~dicke3/nerspcs/chown.html) following command:

```
chown www-data:www-data var/brute-force.ini
```

enable right to write and unlock the access to Magento Connect Manager